# When and where does Panels get the title out of a View?

Tags: 7, views, panels

Two part question about Drupal 7, [Panels 3](http://drupal.org/project/panels), and [Views 3](http://drupal.org/project/views).

I have a view that I have added to a content area in a panels page.  Right now, the title from the display is being used as the pane title.  I need to dynamically set the title of this from a module.

1. When does Panels pull out the display title from the view?
2. Where exactly does it pull it out from?

I cannot seem to override this from any view hook.  For example,

```
function foo_views_pre_view (&$view, &$display_id, &$args)
{
    $view->display[$view->current_display]->display_options["title"] = "Foo";
}
```

doesn't seem to affect the pane title, though the value does propagate through all of the other view hooks.

I suspect I can create a workaround and use a custom block instead of the view directly, but I would rather not do that in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was hoping that someone would answer this, so I wouldn't have to answer my own question when I found the solution.

Credit goes to a co-worker (who doesn't really post here) who reminded me that you also need to update the handler:

```
function foo_views_pre_view (&$view, &$display_id, &$args)
{
  $view->display[$view->current_display]->display_options["title"] =
  $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->options["title"] = "Foo";
}
```

When you do this, the title does propagate properly to the pane title.

Comment: In my case I had to change `$view->display['default']->handler->options['title']` rather than the `$view->current_display`.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal grabs the view title from the view itself when the view is rendered.

You can over ride this in the panels settings area, by manually setting it.

[image]

Revision:

Have you tried doing this with a preprocess function something like

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars) {
 if ($vars['pane']->type == 'node_title') {
  $vars['template_files'][] = 'panels-pane-node-title';
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as my question states, I specifically need to set the title from within a module and not the UI.

Comment: The pane preprocess is less than ideal because at this point the $pane->content has rendered content, so which particular view/display was used is now gone.