# views attachment title

Tags: views

I am using a view page with some attachments. 
For each attachment, I need to display the title : it's right in the preview, I can see the attachment's title, but not in the rendered page. 
How can I fix this please?

zorglub

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the page title of view and set custom title for it](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12135/modify-the-page-title-of-view-and-set-custom-title-for-it)

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't this specifically related to getting the attachments to show info, instead of the page title? I'd say that's not a dup.

Answer (score 2):

As a pretty easy workaround, you could set up a `views-view.tpl.php` on your own sites that prints `$view->get_title()` for the title on the attachments.